# How to check if server is reachable in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I want to check if the server my app is trying reach is reachable (When internet is reachable) before making a request.

I am using Fetch API and right now I am using function timeout which works well but my question is is there any way by which I can check if server is reachable.

I tried using [all-reacheable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-all-reachable) npm package and added following code but I do not get any call back response.

```
isReachable([
    'http://aposddasd.com',
    'http://google.com'
], (err, reachable, host) => {
  console.log('Server is' + reachable); //=> false
  console.log('App log' +  host); //=> 'http://aposddasd.com'
});
```

Can you help me with what is best way to achieve this?

Comment: I have a feeling that `all-reachable` might not work on React Native because it uses a custom implementation of the fetch API as an abstraction of the device's own HTTP layer. Is there any reason why you'd like to check that the host is reachable before making the request? Fetch and promises make handling HTTP errors quite easy and might give your users a better experience.

Comment: Incase my server is down, Fetch API takes about good 120 seconds before it catches an error, So I am looking for something quick, I added function timeout but would like to know if there is some better option,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `Promise.race()` which will return the first promise to resolve or reject - they're pretty awesome actually! Checkout the docs here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Here's a simple function which times out after 3ms - it's using httpbin to simulate a delay of 5s:

```
const isAvailable = () => {
    const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 300, 'Request timed out');
    });

    const request = fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/5');

    return Promise
        .race([timeout, request])
        .then(response => alert('It worked :)'))
        .catch(error => alert('It timed out :('));
}

isAvailable();
```

Checkout the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/edcs/8Lcg8a8j/10/

Comment: Yes - you make a new promise which gets rejected after 300ms, then you can 'race' as many fetches as you like as `fetch()` returns a promise. The first promise to complete gets resolved. So, if the timeout promise gets rejected before the fetches, you can assume that your server is unreachable.

Comment: returns It timed out :( on  android

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid if there is any function for that. But you can put the Fetch API inside a javascript setTimeout() and give it for example 20 seconds. if you don't get results by 20 seconds, probably server is not reachable.

```
setTimeout({ this.FetchData(); }, 20000);
```